# SQL statement with conditions on year

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I am a newbie to SQL and I am trying to add conditions in my SQL query.

I have 4 product pricing file for each year and another table for products.

```
price_table_2020
price_table_2019
price_table_2019
```

All the tables have the data as follows

`price_table_2020`:

```
product  price   product_description
-------------------------------------
ball      100    plastic ball
ink        80    ink for pen
pen      1000    pen
bucket    200    bucket
```

`price_table_2019`:

```
product  price   product_description
------------------------------------
ball      90     plastic ball
ink       70     ink for pen
pen      900     pen
bucket   100     bucket
```

`price_table_2018`:

```
product  price   product_description
-------------------------------------
ball      80     plastic ball
ink       60     ink for pen
pen      800     pen
bucket   300     bucket
```

Product table looks like this:

```
product invoice_year
---------------------
pen     2019
ball    2020
ink     2020
```

Depending upon the invoice year, I am supposed to get the respective product's price from the respective tables.

Expected output as below:

```
product invoice_year   price
----------------------------
pen     2019           900
ball    2020           100
ink     2020            80
```

I am able to get the price from one of the table as below

```
select A.price, B.product, B.product_description 
from product A 
inner join price_table_2020 B on A.product = B.product
```

Can someone help how to do if I have to  include the logic based on `product.invoice_year`?  Thanks.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should tag SQL requests always with the DBMS you are asking them for. The products can be quite different in their SQL dialects.

Comment: Noted @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is difficult, to say the least. I would highly recommend restructuring your tables to put all the price data in one table, adding a `year` column to that table to indicate which year the price is applicable to. Then your query becomes simple:

```
SELECT pr.product,
       pr.invoice_year,
       pc.price
FROM product pr
JOIN price_table pc ON pc.product = pr.product
                   AND pc.year = pr.invoice_year
ORDER BY pr.invoice_year, pr.product
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
product     invoice_year    price
pen         2019            900
ball        2020            100
ink         2020            80
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76xEH7QspZfPuwLtX32LWk/0)

If you *have* to maintain your current table structure, you could emulate the `price` table above using a `UNION` of all the `price` tables:

```
SELECT pr.product,
       pr.invoice_year,
       pc.price
FROM product pr
JOIN (
  SELECT *, 2020 AS year
  FROM price_table_2020
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 2019
  FROM price_table_2019
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 2018
  FROM price_table_2018
) pc ON pc.product = pr.product
    AND pc.year = pr.invoice_year
ORDER BY pr.invoice_year, pr.product
```

The output of this query is the same. The downside of this approach is that you have to edit the query every time you add a new `price` table.

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iSNXnUjf35QebV2x9RvhuU/2)

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go.

Comment: It should be `UNION ALL` though. There are no duplicates to removed (which is what `UNION [DISTINCT]` is for).

Comment: Yeah, the alternatives (I like that we both have a different one) are not very palatable.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I forgot to mention that I only have invoide_date in 2020-09-13 in my procut table. I could parse it as YEAR(invoice_date) . I get an error when I add like this pc.year = pr.YEAR(invoice_date)   Could you please tell me how to add in this the above query. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Lilly it should be `pc.year = YEAR(pr.invoice_date)`

Comment: @Nick. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very bad data model. Data belongs in tables, not in the database structure. The year is mere data (as can be seen from your product table), and it should be data in a price table. Instead you have a separate price table per year. This makes writing queries a nuisance, as can be seen below. I recommend you change this data model.

```
select p.*, coalesce(p2018.price, p2019.price, p2020.price) as invoice_price
from products p
left join price_table_2018 p2018 on p2018.product = p.product and p.invoice_year = 2018
left join price_table_2019 p2019 on p2019.product = p.product and p.invoice_year = 2019
left join price_table_2020 p2020 on p2020.product = p.product and p.invoice_year = 2020
order by p.product;
```

Comment: It would be interesting to benchmark the two alternatives.